# Mod Crashing ETS2

Tags: technical-issues, mods, euro-truck-simulator-2

I recently updated Euro Truck Simulator 2 to version 1.24.4.3. I am a very avid fan of big American Trucks, particularly the Freightliner Line of trucks. I downloaded the latest version of the mod for 1.24.4.3, and installed it as usual. But when I go to the Volvo Dealer, where the trucks are normally, the game crashes and I have to restart the entire game again.

Strangely enough though, I have used a very early version of the same truck mod throughout the history of game versions, and that truck works fine. It seems that the latest version of the mod is causing some confusion. I still drive that truck today.

Here are the things I have tried

1. I have loaded the recent mod with the older mod, to see if the newer
   mod can use the older mod's base of the truck
2. I have removed all my other mods except for the one in question, but
   the game still crashes
3. I have increased priority to the mod in question, that too did not
   work.

I looked into the game.log file in the game folder, and it gave me a whole range of errors, ranging from an error failing to open the mod files, the files being in read only format, and the files of the truck being malformed. The biggest error is saying that it failed to load the model geometry.

I am at wits end with this mod

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps contact the mod creator?  Maybe others are having the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem with the mod. What I had to do was to add the mod's previous versions(All of them), as well as having a base file of the mod, so that it can render itself. Then the mod would render, and finally load.

It also became apparent that the file that was causing the crash was in fact the steering wheel in the latest update of the mod!